# How to send and display an image in a second activity using putExtra()?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am completely new to Android Studio and would like some help. I'm trying to pass an image ID from my FirstActivity class to my SecondActivity Class. The program is supposed to display a horizontally sliding row of buttons containing the text description of a work of art (this part works). When a button is clicked, ImageActivity should be launched to display the corresponding work of art (application stops running in the emulator).

Any ideas? Thank you! Again, I'm totally new to this, so any insight, even if it's really obvious, would be helpful.

Here's MainActivity:

```
    private LinearLayout mLinearList;
    private String id;
    private Painting painting;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        //REFERENCE THE SCROLLABLE LAYOUT STRUCTURE IN MAIN_SCREEN.XML
        mLinearList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearList);

        //FILL THE SCROLLABLE LAYOUT STRUCTURE WITH PAINTINGS
        fillTextCarousel();

    }

    private void fillTextCarousel() {

        // POPULATE THE LINEAR LIST CAROUSEL WITH PAINTINGS AND DESCRIPTIONS
        Button buttonItem;

        for (int i = 0; i < RenaissanceDatabase.description.length; i++) {
            //STORE THE INDIVIDUAL PAINTINGS AS BUTTONS
            buttonItem = new Button(this);


            painting = new Painting(RenaissanceDatabase.description[i], RenaissanceDatabase.id[i]);

            //USE THE CONTENT DESCRIPTION PROPERTY TO STORE
            //PAINTING DATA

            buttonItem.setContentDescription(painting.getDescription());
            buttonItem.setText(painting.getDescription());

            //SET AN ONCLICK LISTENER FOR THE TEXT BUTTON
            buttonItem.setOnClickListener(displayPainting);

            //ADD THE IMAGE BUTTON TO THE SCROLLABLE LINEAR LIST
            mLinearList.addView(buttonItem);
        }
    }

    private View.OnClickListener displayPainting = new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View btn) {
         // COLLECT THE IMAGE STORED FOR THE PAINTING
             Intent imgIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageActivity.class);
             imgIntent.setAction(imgIntent.ACTION_SEND);
             imgIntent.putExtra("image_id:",painting.getId());
             startActivity(imgIntent);

         }
    };
```

Here's what I have so far for ImageActivity:

```
private Button imgButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    painting = new Painting(RenaissanceDatabase.description[index], RenaissanceDatabase.id[index]);

    Intent objIntent=this.getIntent();
    ImageView art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    art.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(getExtra()));;
}

private String getExtra(){
    String image_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_id");
    return image_id;
}
```

And here is what the paintings database looks like:

```
    public static String description[] = {
            "Venus of Urbino\nTitan, 1538",
            "St. John the Baptist\nLeonardo da Vinci, 1516",
            "Protrait of Baldassare Castiglione\nRaphael, 1515",
            "The Entombent of Christ\nCaravaggio, 1603",
            "Coronation of the Virgin\nFra Angelico, 1435",
            "Mars and Venus\n Sandro Bottcelli, 1483"};

    public static int id[] = {
            R.drawable.painting1, // VENUS OF URBINO
            R.drawable.painting2, // ST.JOHN BAPTIST
            R.drawable.painting3, // BALDASSARE
            R.drawable.painting4, // ENTOMBENT OF CHRIST
            R.drawable.painting5, // CORONOATION
            R.drawable.painting6  // MARS AND VENUS
    };
```

Here's the stack trace when it crashes:

03-21 15:41:01.283 14004-14004/edu.augustana.csc490.renaissancepaintings E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.augustana.csc490.renaissancepaintings/edu.augustana.csc490.renaissancepaintings.ImageActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
                                                                                               at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
                                                                                               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:355)
                                                                                               at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
                                                                                               at edu.augustana.csc490.renaissancepaintings.ImageActivity.onCreate(ImageActivity.java:40)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-21 15:41:03.083 14004-14004/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14004 SIG: 9

Comment: post the stacktrace that is generated when your app crashes

Comment: Thank you, just edited it to the most recent code and the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems, you have a typo in:

1) imgIntent.putExtra("image_id:",painting.getId());

`image_id:` has a colon in it, and the corresponding key retrieval does not have a colon. So that explains your null.

2) in your retrieval, stop casting to Integer, and instead use `getIntExtra("image_id")` instead of `getStringExtra`

In the future, you can also check to see if your Intent Bundle contains the key you are looking for, before you try to retrieve it, preventing a null exception from crashing you app, using `getIntent().hasExtra("key")`

Comment: Thank you! this helped a lot and I feel like I'm almost there. The program no longer crashes and displays an image when the buttons are clicked. However, it keeps only displaying the very last image in the array. I've posted this as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143316/correct-integer-not-being-passed-through-putextra    Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
art.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(getExtra())));
```

by

```
art.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(getExtra()));
```

Comment: Thanks Shadab-- I still get an 'invalid int: "null"' exception when I change that line, though. Am I using putExtra() correctly in MainActivity to send the painting IDs? And am I pulling that information correctly in the getExtra() method in ImageActivity?